# VerifyError; Expecting a stack map frame in method controllers.Secure$Security.authentify

Tags: playframework

I followed the tutorial introducing the Play framework, but it gives me an error:

> Execution exception 
>   VerifyError occured : Expecting a stack map frame in method controllers.Secure$Security.authentify(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z at offset 33

I'm not sure what I did wrong. The code I'm using (snippets):

```
package controllers;

..

@With(Secure.class)
public class Application extends Controller 
{
    @Before
    public static void setConnectedUser() 
    {
        if (Security.isConnected()) 
        {
            User user = User.find("byEmail", Security.connected()).first();
            user.password = null;
            renderArgs.put("user", user);
        }
    }

    ...
```

For the Security class:

```
package controllers;

import models.*;

public class Security extends Secure.Security {    
    static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        return User.connect(username, password) != null;
    }
}
```

I also added the secure module to dependencies.yml which loads correctly after restarting Play framework. I added the secure model to my routes. Eclipse gives no errors; error only occurs on execution time. The Secure.Security class does actually have the public static isConnected method available. I'm using the most recent version for the Play framework (1.2.2).

Comment: I can see authentify is @Deprecated in Play-source, but not sure where it got called, if this is causing the exception?

Comment: freeone3000 @ irc.freenode.org#java suggested it could be related to the fact I'm using JDK 1.7; something with bytecode and validation. Could it be related to `invokedynamic`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The message group for Play has discussed that there are some issues with JDK1.7, and that Play does not officially support this yet. If possible, please try with JDK 6, and see if you still get this error.

If you are confined to JDK7, you can use the option

```
java.source=1.6
```

in your application.conf file.

*Update 18th August 2011:* Nicolas Leroux recently sent out a message on Twitter to say that Java 7 support had been added to Play in the master branch. It probably won't make the 1.2.3 release, but will make the release after that.

Comment: Play 1.2.4 RC3 supports Java 7 - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/t2TQl3neUBI

Comment: indeed it does. It did miss 1.2.3, but as it was in master, it automatically got added to 1.2.4.

Comment: Contrary to what the announcement regarding 1.7-support says, this seems to be the case.  Not only did this solve the problem for me, but I saw a similar problem trying to use the SecureSocial plugin and saw some talk about 1.7 being the issue there too (though I didn't try to fix it at that point so I'm not positive of the outcome there).  But I can certify that I am using Play 1.2.4 and was seeing this same error and that this fixed it.

Comment: the latest release candidate of 1.2.4 had some changes to make it Java 5 backward compatible. As a result this may have re-introduced this error. 1.3.x will not support Java 5, so I would expect this error to go away again in 1.3.x.

Comment: Please note, as per Nicolas's comment, you can do this on Java 1.7 by adding the -XX:-UseSplitVerifier flag to the command line.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same, problem, it seems to come from JDK7 indeed.

I to solve it, add

```
java.source=1.6
```

to the application.conf file, stop the application, delete everything under the tmp directory of the app and restart it, it should work even if you have the JDK 1.7 installed

if you don't delete the files, play will not recompile them and it will not work, even if you go back to the JDK 1.6

Answer (score 8):

you can also use the  `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` flag.

Comment: this works in java 1.7; java 1.8 you should append  -noverify  to the vm options

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I run my play application.
I am using play 1.2.5 and Java 1.7

I just added

> java.source=1.6

in the application.conf.

Then deleted the tmp folder and restart the application and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

It's okay if you wanna use jdk7.
Just make sure that your java path configured properly.
Check "java -version" and "javac -version".

Example path:

- "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin"       <--- do this
- "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\bin"   <--- don't do like this

Comment: The problem reported is actually related to generated bytecode not fully compliant to what java 7 expects, not to the java binary you choose to execute the app