# Play! - Expecting a stack map frame in method controllers

Tags: playframework

I am using the Security module for my Play! application and had it working at one point, but for some reason I did something to make it stop working.  I am getting the following errors:

> Execution exception VerifyError occured : Expecting a stack map frame
>   in method
>   controllers.Secure$Security.authentify(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z
>   at offset 33
>
> In {module:secure}/app/controllers/Secure.java (around line 61)

I saw the post below, but, even though I **am** using Java 7, it looks like Play! works ok with 7 now.  I am using Play 1.2.4.

[VerifyError; Expecting a stack map frame in method controllers.Secure$Security.authentify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704169/verifyerror-expecting-a-stack-map-frame-in-method-controllers-securesecurity-a)

Here is my Security controller:

```
package controllers;

import models.*;

public class Security extends Secure.Security {

    public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        User user = User.find("byEmail", username).first();
        return user != null && user.password.equals(password);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

seems to be a common issue with 1.7 (cobertura has the same issue).

Down grade to 1.6, do a play clean and it starts working for me again.